# Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field extension of $F$. Show that the algebraic closure of $F$ in $K$ is an algebraic closure of $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field extension of $F$. Show that
the algebraic closure of $F$ in $K$ is an algebraic closure of $F$.

I have been thinking a lot about this problem but I do not quite understand what it is that asks me the problem, this result is not obvious? What to try? I appreciate any explanation, thank you very much.

Comment: Yes it is obvious. $K$ is a field containing $F$ where any polynomial $p \in K[x]$ splits completely. Let $L = \{ a \in K, a $ is algebraic over $F\}$. Any polynomial $p \in F[x] \subset K[x]$ splits completely in $K$ and by definition of "algebraic over $F$" its roots are in $L$.

Comment: Hi reuns, wouldn't your choice of p(x) need to be in L[x]?